# Jquery Datepicker with MVC4 and Razor

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, datepicker

I am building my first MVC 4 app and having a little trouble.  In the create.cshtml I have a few text boxes the user can trype in dates.  I want to add a datepicker and from what I have read you cannot use ajax.

I have been looking at the following video [YourTube Video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7ZXj9ojFFk8)

But I cant see how to use it in conjunction with razor.  The code on my create page has a text box for the date that looks like this

```
        <div class="editor-label">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
    <div class="editor-field">
        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ReleaseDate)
    </div>
```

Can anyone offer any advice on how bext to add a datepicker please?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by adding in

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.ReleaseDate, new { id = "ReleaseDate" })
```

The id section at the end

Answer (score 0):

Good but it is not a good idea to use Id, instad you can use class as such you can reuse the code Remember ID changes and if you re using JQuery then you may get wrong results